# How can I open photos from Canon 550D in Photoshop CS5?

Tags: photoshop-cs5

I view my RAW photos from my Canon 550D on my home PC using Canon Zoom Browser. If I transfer them to a USB stick I cannot read them on another PC when I am at my Photoshop CS5 class.

Answer (score 3):

The original version of Photoshop CS5 (which uses Adobe Camera Raw version 6.0) did not support the Canon 550D. Adobe later released Camera Raw version 6.1 which does include support for the 550D and which is also compatible with CS5. The last version of Adobe camera Raw that works with CS5 is version 6.7.

Ask the owner of the PC at your classes if they can update the version of Adobe Camera Raw used by Photoshop CS5 to version 6.7. It is a [free download from Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=5371).

Answer (score 1):

I assume your question is, how can I read them on another PC? Photoshop CS5 should include Adobe Camera Raw, which should have no problem reading RAW files. Failing that, you could see if the class will allow you to download something like RAWTherapee, an open source RAW editor.

Comment: Or just convert them to JPEG before going to class.

Comment: CS5 as originally shipped/released included *Adobe Camera Raw (ACR) 6.0* before the 550D was released. ACR versions 6.1 and following support RAW files from the 550D. The last version of ACR compatible with CS5 is ACR 6.7.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Adobe DNG Converter](http://www.adobe.com/en/products/photoshop/extend.displayTab2.html#downloads) to convert your Canon Raw files to Adobe's Digital Negative (DNG) format.